# What would happen to the solution of primal SVM problem we had 0 in constraint instead of 1

Tags: machine-learning, svm, lagrange-multipliers

That is, what if the constraint was $y^i(w^Tx^i + b) ≥ 0$

Answer (score 1):

Then $\mathbf{w} = \mathbf{0}$, $b = 0$ satisfies every constraint, but that's not a useful solution.

Stanford Prof. Stephen Boyd has an excellent discussion in [lecture 13 of his Convex Optimization Course](https://youtu.be/FkPLteYMK40?t=44).